# Best practice of consuming JSON data on client side (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json

I have a REST api which dumps some json data (user info, etc). Now I need to use that data to:

1. construct html tables,
2. plat graphs using some js graphing lib,
3. Do some calculations over some fields and again display them.

So, essentially I need to do some processing on that data and then display the refined form.

I am new to javascript and trying to understand what is the best practice to construct the html?

I am using jquery to make the ajax call and the success part looks something like this:

```
success:function(data){
  $('#show_data_here').empty();
  generated_html  = construct_html(data);
  $('#show_data_here').html(generated_html);
}
```

Now, the `construct_html(data)` function is getting really ugly since the json I am receiving is huge (800 lines) and I have alot (~10) graphs to display on one page. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a start try breaking them down into functions that perform each task.
Then within each task, you may have sub-tasks. break them down again.

```
success:function(data){
  constructTable(data.tableData);
  grabLib.create(data.graphData);
  updateCalculations(data.tableData);
}

function constructTable(data)
{
  var html = '';
  // foreach
  $('table tbody').empty().html(html);
}

// etc
```

Idealy you would want to be dealing with objects that could perform the tasks for you, but your first steps would be breaking down the functionality. into smaller chunks.

Comment: I am tempted to go with this approach and hope things don't get messy.

Comment: If they're getting messy consider using a object in javascript. You'll be able to contain the functionality within one area: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp, then just create each object as a separate js file. Should keep things nice & neat.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of html you are constructing you may want to consider using a templating framework like [JsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender).

if the html you are constructing follows a definite pattern, this might be the way to go.

Comment: Jquery Templates are no longer supported.

Comment: @John ok .. maybe i'll just leave jsrender then.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas i haven't tried that. will definitely check it out.

Comment: The web-site [handlebarsjs.com](http://handlebarsjs.com/) contains a "getting stared" guide. Check it out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972195/whats-wrong-with-this-handlebars-js-code